# Multithreading 70 similar commands and receiving output from each

Tags: multithreading, bash, background, return-value

I need to parse 70 identically **formatted** files (different data), repeatedly, to process some information on demand from each file. I.e. (as a simplified example)...

```
find /dir -name "MYDATA.bam" | while read filename; do
  dir=$(echo ${filename} | awk -F"/" '{ print $(NF-1)}')
  ARRAY[$dir]=$(samtools view ${filename} | head -1)
done
```

Since it's 70 files, I wanted each `samtools view` command to run as an independent thread...so I didn't have to wait for each command to finish (each command takes around 1 second.) Something like...

```
# $filename will = "/dir/DATA<id#>/MYDATA.bam"
# $dir then = "DATA<id#>" as the ARRAY key.
find /dir -name "MYDATA.bam" | while read filename; do
  dir=$(echo ${filename} | awk -F"/" '{ print $(NF-1)}')
  command="$(samtools view ${filename} | head -1)
  ARRAY[$dir]=$command &
done 
wait # To get the array loaded
(... do stuff with $ARRAY...)
```

But I can't seem to find the syntax to get all the commands called in the background, but still have "result" receive the (correct) output.

I'd be running this on a slurm cluster, so I WOULD actually have 70 cores available to run each command independently (theoretically making that step take 1-2 seconds concurrently, instead of 70 seconds consecutively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this simply with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

doit() {
   dir=$(echo "$1" | awk -F"/" '{print $(NF-1)}')
   result=$(samtools view "$1" | head -1)
   echo "$dir:$result"
}

# export doit() function for subshells of "parallel" to use
export -f doit

# find the files and pass, null-terminated, to GNU Parallel
find somewhere -name "MYDATA.bam" -print0 | parallel -0 doit {}
```

It will run one copy of `samtools` per CPU core you have available, but you can easily change that, with `parallel -j 8` if you just want 8 at a time, for example.

If you want the outputs in order, use `parallel -k ...`

I am not familiar with **slurm** clusters, so you may have to read up on how to tell **GNU Parallel** about your nodes, or let it just run 8 at a time or however many cores your main node has.

Comment: Worked very well. Thanks!

Comment: If you prefer avoiding the function something like this `parallel --tagstring '{= $_=(split m:/:)[1] =}' 'samtools view {} | head -1'` will do almost the same (\t instead of :).

Answer (score 1):

Capturing the output of a process even when spawned in the background blocks the shell. Here a small example:

```
echo "starting to sleep in the background"
sleep 2 &
echo "some printing in the foreground"
wait
echo "done sleeping"
```

This will produce the following output:

```
starting to sleep in the background
some printing in the foreground
<2 second wait>
done sleeping
```

If however you capture like this:

```
echo "starting to sleep in the background"
output=$(sleep 2 &)
echo "some printing in the foreground"
wait
echo "done sleeping"
```

The following happens:

```
starting to sleep in the background
<2 second wait>
some printing in the foreground
done sleeping
```

The actual waiting happened on the assignment of the output. By the time the `wait` statement is reached there is no more background process and thus no waiting.

So one way would be to pipe the output into files and stitch them back together 
after the `wait`. This is a bit awkward.

A simpler solution might be to use [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), a tool that deals with
collecting the output of parallel processes. It works particularly well when the output is line based.

Comment: Note that `wait` doesn't do anything in your second example, because the current shell has no jobs running in the background. (The background job is associated with the shell created by the command substitution.)

Comment: Hi @FelixLeipold  Thanks for the answer. The bump I ran into with this was the pipe (```| head -1```). If I tried ```test=$(samtools view ${filename} | head -1000000  &)```...the script would wait for samtools to finish, and then run ```head``` in the background. If ```test=$(samtools view ${filename} & | head -1000000)``` I#d get the errors **-bash: command substitution: line 143: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
-bash: command substitution: line 143: `samtools view ${filename} & | head -1000000 )' **

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with just Bash. This snippet show how you can run each command in the background and write the results to stdout. The inner loop reads in these results and adds them to your array. You'll probably have to tweak this to make it work.

```
while read -r dir && read -r data; do                                       
   ARRAY[$dir]="$data"                                                      

done < <(   
  # sub shell level one   

  find /dir -name "MYDATA.bam" | while read filename; do                    
    (        
      # sub shell level two

      # run each task in parallel, output will be in the following format   
      # "directory"                                                                                                                                                          
      # "result"                                                            
      # ...                                                                 

      dir=$(awk -F"/" '{ print $(NF-1)}' <<< "$filename")                   
      printf "%s\n%s\n" \                                                   
        "$dir" "$(samtools view "$filename" | head -1)"                     
    ) &                                                                             
  done                                                                              
)
```

The key is that `( command; command ) &` runs each command in a new sub shell in the background, so the top level shell can continue to the next task.

The `< <(command)` allows us to redirect the stdout of a subprocess to the stdin of another shell command. This is how we can read the results into our variable and have the variable be available later.